# UIImage - Content mode fit and right position - Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimage, contentmode

How can I move the image to the right?

```
img.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: This is a bit awkward actually and won't work out of the box. You can potentially do this using constraints and wrapping the image in a uiview. Otherwise perhaps this open source will help [UIImageViewAligned](https://github.com/sochalewski/UIImageViewAlignedSwift)